# Is $f(x)= \cos(e^x)$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, analysis

As in the topic, my quest is to check (and prove) whether the given function $$f(x)= \cos(e^x)$$is uniformly continuous  on $\left\{\begin{matrix}x \in (-\infty;0]
\\ 
x \in [0; +\infty)
\end{matrix}\right.$ .

My problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to do it. Any hints will be appreciated and do not feel offended if I ask you a question which you consider stupid, but such are the beginnings. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know what "uniformly continuous" means?

Comment: On $(-\infty,0]$, use the mean value theorem to show is it $1$-Lipschitz.

Comment: that i can "draw it without hettin goff pencil"

Comment: No, that's (somehow) continuous.

Comment: I know Lipschitz but what is 1-Lipschitz?

Comment: there is no challenge in proving this for the negative $x$ part... the other part is a bit challenging...

Comment: $1$-Lipschitz means that the Lipschitz constant is $1$. But you're right, it is enough to say that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is uniform continuity for $x \in (-\infty,0]$, because the derivative $f'(x)=-e^x \sin(e^x)$ is bounded there ($|f'(x)| \le 1$ there):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, and suppose $|x_1-x_2|<\delta=\varepsilon$. Apply Lagrange's mean value theorem: $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|f'(\xi)| |x_1-x_2| \le 1 \cdot |x_1-x_2|<\varepsilon$. ($\xi$ is some number between $x_1$ and $x_2$).

There is **no** uniform continuity on $[0,+\infty)$ though. To see this look at the pairs of points $x_n=\ln (2\pi n),y_n=\ln((2n+1) \pi)$, they get closer than any $\delta$, yet the distance between their f-value is always 2.

Comment: Are you sure the distance of the $f$-values of $x_n$ and $y_n$ is always $2$, and not $1$? Isn't $\cos (2n\pi)=0$ and $\cos(2n\pi+\pi)=-1$ for all $n$?

Comment: @ThomasE. Really? $\cos (2n\pi)=0$?

Comment: @julien. Ah, shoot. It's $1$ :) made a silly mistake when drawing the circle. Then their difference is $2$ as wanted.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative is not needed, you can replace $\cos$ with any nonconstant periodic continuous function $g$:

Let $g\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be

- continuous
- non-constant
- periodic.

Then for any $a\in \mathbb R$, the function $f(x):=g(e^x)$ is

- uniformly continuos on $(-\infty,a]$
- not uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$

*Proof:*
Every continuous function is continous on compact intervals, therefore every periodic continous function is uniformly continuous

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$ if  $|x-y|<\delta$.
Wlog. $\delta<e^a$. Then $0<1-\delta e^{-a}<1$ ad hence $\delta':=-\ln(1-\delta e^{-a})>0$.
Now consider $x,y<a$ with $|x-y|<\delta'$. Wlog. $x\le y$.
Then $$e^y-e^x=e^y(1-e^{x-y})<e^a(1-e^{-\delta'})=\delta$$
and hence $$ |f(x)-f(y)|=|g(e^x)-g(e^y)|<\epsilon.$$
Thus $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,a]$.

As $g$ is not constant, there exist $x_1, x_2$ with $g(x_1)\ne g(x_2)$.
Let $\epsilon=|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|>0$.
Let $p>0$ be a period of $g$.
No matter how small we choose $\delta>0$, for sufficiently big $k\in\mathbb Z$ (especially with $x_i+kp>e^a>0$), we have $|\ln(x_1+kp)-\ln(x_2+kp)|<\delta$ because $$\ln(x_1+kp)-\ln(x_2+kp)=\ln\frac{x_1/k+p}{x_2/k+p}\to\ln1=0$$ as $k\to+\infty.$
But then $$|f(\ln(x_1+kp))-f(\ln(x_2+kp))|=|g(x_1+kp)-g(x_2+kp)|=|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|=\epsilon $$
so we se ethat $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$. $_\square$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'(x)=-e^x\sin{(e^x)}.$

Let $x_n=\ln{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n\right)}, \;\;  y_n= \ln{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n\right)}.$ 
Then $$|x_n-y_n| = {\ln{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n\right)} -\ln{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n\right)}}=\ln{\dfrac{\dfrac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n}{{\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n}}}=\\ = \ln{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{1+12 n }\right)}\sim \dfrac{1}{1+12 n }, \;\; n\to \infty .$$ 
By the mean value ( Lagrange's) theorem $$|f(x_n)-f(y_n|=|f'(\xi_n)|\cdot|x_n-y_n|=e^{\xi_n}|\sin(e^{\xi_n})|\cdot|x_n-y_n|\geqslant \\ \geqslant e^{x_n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+12 n }=\dfrac{\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n}{2+24n} \underset{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow} \dfrac {\pi}{12},$$
which proves that $f$ is not uniformly continuous  on $[0,\;+\infty)$.

Comment: If by Lagrange theorem you mean the mean value theorem, how do you do that?

Comment: Ah, ok. I just thought it was much more trouble than the explicit estimate by Michael Touitou. Thanks for the edit, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is uniformly continuous on the interval $(-\infty,0]$. To see that, use the mean value theorem twice.

**Added:** Exploiting the identies $ |\cos(t) - \cos(z)|\leq | t-z | $
and  $ |e^x - e^y| \leq | {x}-{y} | $ on $(-\infty,0]$, which they can be proved by the mean value theorem, we have

$$ | \cos(e^{x}) - \cos(e^{y})|\leq | e^{x}-e^{y} |\leq| x-y |< \epsilon=\delta. $$

Comment: Why twice? I think once is enough.

Comment: @julien: he needs to bound $|e^x-e^y|$ too.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal. He only needs bound for the derivative of $f$.

Comment: $|f'(x)|=|e^x\sin (e^x)|\leq 1$ so (mvt, once)  $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz, so $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Do not forget it is a composed function.

Comment: I don't forget it... I did the chain rule. To find $\|f'\|_\infty\leq 1$ on $(-\infty,0)$ so $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$. Mvt, once...

Comment: Apparently, you think that the mvt yields $f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(e^x-e^y)$ for some $c$ in $(x,y)$. Can't you see the problem?